# Pandas - different set of keywords for different IDs, search if string contains the keyword

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 sets of dataframes

```
   IDs    Keywords
0  1234   APPLE ABCD
1  1234   ORANGE
2  1234   LEMONS
3  5346   ORANGE
4  5346   STRAWBERRY
5  5346   BLUEBERRY
6  8793   TEA COFFEE
```

Second Dataframe:

```
   IDs    Name         
0  1234   APPLE ABCD ONE
1  5346   APPLE ABCD   
2  1234   STRAWBERRY YES 
3  8793   ORANGE AVAILABLE  
4  8793   TEA AVAILABLE
5  8793   TEA COFFEE
```

I would like to search for the keywords based on IDs level, 
use it for the second dataframe and search for a column:Name 
if the keywords contains in the Name for the same IDs exist, provide any indicator True, otherwise False.

For Example:
For IDs 1234, APPLE ABCD, ORANGE, LEMONS are the keywords. So in the second dataframe:
Index Row 0 with APPLE ABCD ONE will be True as "APPLE ABCD" is part of the keywords

For IDs 5346, ORANGE, STRAWBERRY, BLUEBERRY are the keywords. So in the second dataframe, Index Row 1 with APPLE ABCD will be False.

```
   IDs    Name               Indicator
0  1234   APPLE ABCD ONE     True
1  5346   APPLE ABCD         False
2  1234   STRAWBERRY YES     False
3  8793   ORANGE AVAILABLE   False
4  8793   TEA AVAILABLE      False
5  8793   TEA COFFEE         True
```

Comment: what is the second dataframe, anything tries so far that will help more to answer?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Please see my answer for a simpler and more pandas-like code. It seems to work for the sample data provided above - hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
# create a list of tuples from 1st dataframe
kw = list(zip(df1.IDs, df1.Keywords))

def func(ids, name):
    if (ids,name.split(" ")[0]) in kw:
        return True
    return False

df2['Indicator'] = df2.apply(lambda x: func(x['IDs'],x['Names']), axis=1)
```

**Edit**

Create a list of tuples with combination of IDs and Keywords

```
kw = list(zip(df1.IDs, df1.Keywords))
# [(1234, 'APPLE ABCD'), (1234, 'ORANGE'), (1234, 'LEMONS'), (5346, 'ORANGE'), (5346, 'STRAWBERRY'), (5346, 'BLUEBERRY'), (8793, 'TEA COFFEE')]

unique_kw = list(df1['Keywords'].unique())
# ['APPLE ABCD', 'ORANGE', 'LEMONS', 'STRAWBERRY', 'BLUEBERRY', 'TEA COFFEE']

def samp(x):
    for u in unique_kw:
        if u in x:
            return u
    return None

# This will fetch the keywords from column which will be used for compare  
df2['indicator'] = df2['Names'].apply(lambda x: samp(x))

df2['indicator'] = df2.apply(lambda x: True if (x['IDs'], x['indicator']) in kw else False, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    IDs     Names               indicator
0   1234    APPLE ABCD ONE      True
1   5346    APPLE ABCD          False
2   1234    NO STRAWBERRY YES   False
3   8793    ORANGE AVAILABLE    False
4   8793    TEA AVAILABLE       False
5   8793    TEA COFFEE          True
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! what happens if I have two keywords, which should be taken together for consideration? I have updated the questions according to keywords with two words..

Comment: Clarify one more thing, is there a possibility that your `Names` column may contain values like `one ABCD APPLE`  where keywords appears later in string?

Comment: one ABCD APPLE will not be considered true as the keyword should be APPLE ABCD. However, Name can have "BANANA APPLE ABCD ORANGE" and this is considered True. "TODAY IS APPLE ABCD" considered true.

Comment: See the Edit. Hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

#### You can do this using mostly `pandas` operations, which will be more efficient as well.

```
# Let there be two DataFrames: kw_df, name_df

# Group all keywords of each ID in a list, associate it with the names
kw_df = kw_df.groupby('IDs').aggregate({'Keywords': list})
merge_df = name_df.join(kw_df, on='IDs')

# Check if any keyword is in the name
def is_match(name, kws):
    return any(kw in name for kw in kws)

merge_df['Indicator'] = merge_df.apply(lambda row: is_match(row['Name'], row['Keywords']), axis=1)
print(merge_df)
```

This gives output as follows:

```
    IDs              Name                         Keywords  Indicator
0  1234    APPLE ABCD ONE     [APPLE ABCD, ORANGE, LEMONS]       True
1  5346        APPLE ABCD  [ORANGE, STRAWBERRY, BLUEBERRY]      False
2  1234    STRAWBERRY YES     [APPLE ABCD, ORANGE, LEMONS]      False
3  8793  ORANGE AVAILABLE                     [TEA COFFEE]      False
4  8793     TEA AVAILABLE                     [TEA COFFEE]      False
5  8793        TEA COFFEE                     [TEA COFFEE]       True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` while using `groupby` and `lambda` as follows:

```
>>> df.merge(df2).groupby(['IDs','Name']).apply(lambda x: any(x['Name'].str.contains('|'.join(x['Keywords'])))).rename('Indicator').reset_index()
    IDs              Name  Indicator
0  1234        APPLE ABCD       True
1  1234    STRAWBERRY YES      False
2  5346        APPLE ABCD      False
3  8793  ORANGE AVAILABLE      False
4  8793     TEA AVAILABLE       True
```